How to authenticate using the login page of the front-end server from the back-end authorization server that communicates with restful API
How to authenticate using the login page of the front-end server from the back-end authorization server that communicates with restful API

According to the rfc document, implict and password have been deprecated among grant types in spring-oauth2-server.
So, I would like to use the PKCE type authentication flow among the authorization code types.
Also, I would like to use the login page of my SPA Application as the login page. (SPA Application has separate admin and user purposes. Each has a separate login page.)
(Rather than using the security login page provided by Spring)
composition:
- Authorization + resource server (spring boot 3.3.x + spring oauth2 server) created by me (not usering google or facebook oauth2)
- Gateway server (All communication between servers is done through the gateway server.)
- SPA Application (vue3 - exist admin and user web)

As far as I know, the authorization code with PKCE follows the flow below.
Example configuration:
authentication server - port: 9090
admin front port: 8080

Send client_id, code_challenge, code_challenge_method, redirect_uri(http://localhost:8080), ... as parameters to http://localhost:9090/oauth2/authorize.
The spring security login page appears.
Enter id and pw.
Receive an authorization code.
Post the received authorization code, code_verifier, client_secret, ... to http://localhost:9090/oauth2/token with x-www-form-urlencoded.
Receive access token, refresh token, id token (open id), ...

I roughly understand this, but in number 2, I want to use the SPA login page rather than the spring security login page.
Here, there are separate SPA for ADMIN and SPA for USER.
If you add the following to the security filter chain:
http.securityMatcher("/login", "/logout")
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .exceptionHandling(handler ->
                        handler.authenticationEntryPoint(dynamicLoginEntryPoint) 
                        // check admin application -> redirect: http://localhost:8080/login
                )
                .formLogin(httpSecurityFormLoginConfigurer -> httpSecurityFormLoginConfigurer
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/login") // http://localhost:9090
                        .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                            // ... 
                        })
                        .failureHandler((request, response, exception) ->{
                            // ...
                        })
                )

                .logout(logout ->
                        logout.logoutUrl("/logout")
                );



Access admin front (8080)
If the admin front (8080) does not have an access token, it sends a get request to /oauth2/authorization to the auth server (9090) to receive an authorization code.

parameter :client_id, code_challenge, code_challenge_method, redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080, ...


redirect to localhost:8080/login
Enter id and pw.
Receive an authorization code.
Post the received authorization code, code_verifier, client_secret, ... to http://localhost:9090/oauth2/token with x-www-form-urlencoded.
Receive access token, refresh token, id token (open id), ...

I want to do it this way, but since it's not session-based, I don't remember requesting it with oauth2/authorize?code_challenge=.... How should I solve this situation?

Is there no choice but to use the login page of the authorization server?

If you don't want to use the authorization server for users authentication, don't use OAuth2.
